# How to make Spring Boot only scan and validate imported entities?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have separated my project in multiple modules using Maven. On of the modules is used as a 'common' module which shares entities and other code between modules. I have imported this module within the other modules. A problem arises when launching a module which uses the 'common' module. The module seems to scan for all entities in the common package and tries to validate the schema. This module does not have the SQL permission to access some tables, which results in a validation error.

Is there a way to disable this feature and only validate the schema based on the actually used entities in the code (based on imports)?

Comment: does adding @Autowired(required=false) in common module entity will work for you?

Answer (score -1):

A somewhat vague explanation, I would like to see an immediate problem.

But the first thing that comes to mind: exclude auto jpa support. For your application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Possible, you can exclude also class DataSourceAutoConfiguration.